# Run the root filesystem in RAM persistently

Tags: linux, initramfs

Would it be possible to make a root partition run entirely in a ramdisk? And, at the same time, would it also be possible to make its contents persistent on every boot?

So, for example, would I be able to to create a custom initramfs image that creates a ramdisk in RAM, mount my temporary partition, copy the contents of that partition into the ramdisk, and then switch root into that ramdisk? And, while shutting down, would it also be possible to flush the contents of that ramdisk into this partition to keep the contents of the filesystem persistent? Assuming a surplus of RAM, of course. This would probably not be the most optimal use of RAM, but I'm curious as to if this would be possible for increased I/O speed in comparison to an HDD, or if this is a concept that's simply incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what an InitRAMfs is.  So why bother with the switchroot?

If you need features that RAMFS doesn't have there's a hidden condition in the kernel (I think it was not setting a root device or similar) that causes the initramfs to be loaded as a tmpfs.

So all you need to do is build a tree with all your desired files and pack it in a CPIO archive to be used as the initramfs 'image'.